# How to ADD an API on WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to create a API from my ERP into WSO2 API Manager  ,to access API without use API Manager I need to use a NTLM credential. I want to publish this API into API Manager, but when I trying to create and Publish , I cannot add that credentials and api does not work. where do I submit those credentials?

As you can see on this picture, I'm getting unauthorize.

[API Manager  Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK9w3.png)

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 API Manager v3.1.0 supports basic auth, digest auth, and mutual ssl for backend security. If you want NTLM, then you can use a class mediator. https://medium.com/@nipunadilhara/ntlm-authentication-for-wso2-esb-v6-2-0-9584c3e6713

Comment: But when I create and publish a api i do not have a possibility to add credentials. I just can add the endpoint .

Comment: From this menu, you can create the API. Once you go inside, there is an endpoint menu.

Comment: does not work also. if I use basic Authentication on Postman or browser , it works, if I add on endpoint does not work, see the picture , https://ibb.co/mzXNygk

Comment: Can u publish the API and check this by invoking the API in the gateway? I think this validation send only http head request to the backend and it does not contain the basic authentication header.

Comment: Same error, I published after that I subscreive the product and tried to run, I got this error.